# FreeBSD: Mixing packages and ports?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, bsd-ports

I would like to build the newest port of Firefox (version 4.0.1,1). I currently have the package version installed (3.6.13). How well does the packages/port system handle mixing ports and packages? Will the dependencies be handled correctly?

For example: Firefox 4.0.1 requires nspr-4.8.7 whereas the packaged version is nspr-4.8.6. A whole slew of things (mostly from the gnome2-lite meta-package depend on nspr). If I install the newer version from ports will I completely wreck things?

I guess this begs a larger question: Can I mix packages and ports? Or do I have to pick one and stay with it? If I do decide to build a mixed system, will it be stable? Will there be appropriate dependency checking and resolution?

Comment: I'll let a FreeBSD expert answer, but as far as I know, a package is just a port that someone's compiled for you, so yes, you can mix them freely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ports and packages simultaneously, both use the same package database in `/var/db/pkg`.

Actually, packages are generated by the ports system. For example, `make package` will install a port and generate the binary package for it. Also you can create a package from the currently installed port with the `pkg_create -b` command.

Comment: The `pkg_create -b` seems to be deprecated.